# magnific popup autoplay slideshow

Tags: popup, magnific-popup, autoplay

I am using magnific popup for popup image slideshow. Below is what i have done.

```
$('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
    type:'image',
    delegate: 'a',
    gallery: {
// options for gallery
    enabled: true
},
    image: {
// options for image content type
    titleSrc: 'title'
}
});
```

And this is my HTML Markup

```
<div class="parent-container">
<ul class="row carousel-inner" style="margin:0; padding:0; background:red;">
    <li class="active item gallery-photo" style="margin:0; padding:0; background:red;">
        <a href="images/gallery-1.jpg" title="Image Title Here"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery-1.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="images/gallery-2.jpg" title="Image Title Here"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery-2.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="images/gallery-3.jpg" title="Image Title Here"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery-3.jpg"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now, everything is working fine, but i want the image to change automatically, like when i launch the popup first image will be displayed and then it should change automatically. I am not able to fine anything to make it `auto` in the documentation .

Your efforts will be greatly apprecialted.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it, i am adding this as an answer so that someone else also can benefit out of it.
You just need to add callbacks.
I have added below code after `magnificPopup({})` function. And that will solve the problem images will start moving automatically.

```
callbacks: {
open: {
   setInterval(function() {
        $.magnificPopup.instance.next();
   }, 2000);
}
}
```